# Pymongo - epoch date filter query not working on collection

Tags: mongodb, date, filter, pymongo

I have a Mongodb collection that needs to be filtered by a date field in the document. The date is stored in unix epoch format.

```
myquery = {"created_at": {"$gt": 1623384000}}
docs = mycollection.find(myquery)
```

This should return 200k docs, but its returning more than 1M docs.

However, when I run the filter from MongoDB Compass, I get the right results.

Comment: any examples of the documents you didn't expect returned?

Comment: Its strange. All the dates on the documents returned are less than 1623384000.

Comment: I would still like to see how the documents look in mongo. `db.mycollection.aggregate([{$sample: { size: 5 } }, {$project:{_id:0, created_at:1}}])` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pymongo supports querying the `ISODate` key with Unix Epoch.

You have to manually convert it to pythons `datetime` format before querying it.

```
from datetime import datetime

myquery = {"created_at": {"$gt": datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1623384000)}}
docs = mycollection.find(myquery)
```

Comment: Converting epoch to python's datetime returns 0 docs. Also updated post to show filter works fine in MongoDB compass.

Comment: That's strange, `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1623384000)` is returning `datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 11, 4, 0)` in my local and the example which I provided works fine too. Can you check again? Also, I meant `pymongo` doesn't support epoch not `mongoDB` . Apologies.